# How to change the text color of the error popup for an EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

On ICS, when using a theme based upon `android:Theme.Light` the text in the **error popup** when using `setError(...)` is white, as is the background.

I can fix this issue by adding `<item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#ff000000</item>` to my theme. While this helps I'm a bit worried that by doing that change some other text, that uses `textColorPrimaryInverse` will turn from white to black and perhaps not be visible. I would rather just change that attribute for the `EditText` that displays the **popup** in question or for just that activity.

*Clarification*

I would like to change a property, preferably the text color, of the **popup** that displays the error message when the user enters something wrong into an `EditText`.

Comment: it would be also nice, if the popup's background drawable could be changed. Haven't you find any way to change these properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
editText.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>Error Message!</font>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In code use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int) or http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor(int). They belong to View, but EditText inherits them. The second methiod is easier, the first is more consistant.

Edit: Oh, it is a more hard question. 
Maybe, using EditText.setError(CharSequence error, Drawable icon) you can put error text on the icon? You can set setBounds(Rect) for the icon, so, it could be enough big. The icon can be the color you need.

But I use onKey,beforeTextChanged, onTextChanged and show my own error message as a Toast. For the toast you can use an usual View.

Comment: I guess my question wasn't clear. I'm not trying to change the background of the `EditText` but rather the text color of the popup that shows the error.

Comment: Sorry, then look the addition in the answer.